# Parsing "Nested" Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm getting JSON data back like this:

```
{
"destination_addresses": [
    "67-89 Pacific St, Brooklyn, NY 11201, USA"
],
"origin_addresses": [
    "566 Vermont St, Brooklyn, NY 11207, USA"
],
"rows": [
    {
        "elements": [
            {
                "distance": {
                    "text": "6.5 mi",
                    "value": 10423
                },
                "duration": {
                    "text": "35 mins",
                    "value": 2076
                },
                "status": "OK"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"status": "OK"
```

}

I need to get the distance value and duration value as variables.

So, I know I need to decode this JSON:

```
$distance_data = json_decode($output);
```

And I've tried a ton of variations like:

```
$duration_value = $distance_data['rows']['elements']['duration']['value']);
```

But I know this isn't right. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The "rows" and "elements" are defined as array in json, so you have to access via array index: `$distance_data = json_decode($output, true); $distance_data['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['value']`. Note: if you don't pass `true` as 2nd paramater to json_decode, the result will be stdObject instead of array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a mixture of objects and arrays.  Here's a full run through of your example.

```
// Your JSON response.
$json = '{
"destination_addresses": [
    "67-89 Pacific St, Brooklyn, NY 11201, USA"
],
"origin_addresses": [
    "566 Vermont St, Brooklyn, NY 11207, USA"
],
"rows": [
    {
        "elements": [
            {
                "distance": {
                    "text": "6.5 mi",
                    "value": 10423
                },
                "duration": {
                    "text": "35 mins",
                    "value": 2076
                },
                "status": "OK"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"status": "OK"
}';

// Get JSON Object
$obj = json_decode($json);

// Let's see what's in the object.
print_r($obj);

/*
stdClass Object
(
    [destination_addresses] => Array
        (
            [0] => 67-89 Pacific St, Brooklyn, NY 11201, USA
        )

    [origin_addresses] => Array
        (
            [0] => 566 Vermont St, Brooklyn, NY 11207, USA
        )

    [rows] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [elements] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [distance] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [text] => 6.5 mi
                                            [value] => 10423
                                        )

                                    [duration] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [text] => 35 mins
                                            [value] => 2076
                                        )

                                    [status] => OK
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [status] => OK
)
*/

// Let's pull the value we want using the information above.
// Notice we start with an object, then rows is an array of objects, as is elements.
echo $obj -> rows[0] -> elements[0] -> duration -> value;
```

Comment: Thanks! Excellent explanation that'll help me next time.